# What is minimum holding current in CT based SCR switch?

Tags: scr

I am looking to use a CT based SCR switch to switch an AC contactor. The switch specs list the following:

Off state voltage: 240 VAC RMS max.
Minimum holding current: 10 mA.
On state current: 1.0 AAC RMS max. continuous
Off state leakage: 50 ua @ 240 VAC max.
Peak Non-Repetitive Surge Current: 8 AAC RMS (1 cycle, 60 Hz.)

Does the "minimum holding current" refer to current passing through the CT or the SCR?

Full device specs are at. https://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/CR%20Magnetics%20Inc%20PDFs/CR9300%20Series.pdf

Comment: Generally speaking - holding current refers to the SCR or Triac.

Comment: Usually you talk about holding current for the SCR itself; the CT circuitry is generally user trimmable to some threshold current level so it makes no sense talking of a CT 'holding current'